# Is there any annotation for Spring data JPA to not return the entire entity in JSON? (Rest API (SQL))

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Code: (It's simple)

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Optional<Person> getOne(@PathVariable Long id){
    return personRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Example:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Will",
   "character": {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Batman",
   "power": 100
    }
 }
```

Example of how I would like it:
(Only the entity id, without all fields.)

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Will",
   "character": {
   "id": 1
    }
 }
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql

Comment: I don't want to use Graphql. It's a rest api.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. Add your code for these two entities and I will help you.

Comment: @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Person> getOne(@PathVariable Long id){
        return personRepository.findById(id);
    }

Answer (score 1):

For that you can mark those fields as **@Transient** in entity. Those fields will neither be persisted nor be serialized, de-serialized..